# MATLAB: find and read full lines starting by regular expression within file

Tags: string, matlab

I am trying to extract some data from a file. I have used regexpi MATLAB function successfully when looking for individual words or numerical data. However, now I am trying to real all the information of a line that follows a regular expression.

For example, from the following text in a file:

```
NAME W-VJJAR 2 1.3 20.3 1 1
ID 3.00000E-01 2.80000E-02 1.00000E+01
IT 3.10000E-01 1.12000E-01 1.00000E+01
IM 3.20000E-01 2.88000E-01 1.00000E+01
NAME E4050 2 1.567 CHAN CHIN CHON
ID 3.00000E-01 2.80000E-02 1.00000E+01
IT 3.10000E-01 1.18000E-01 0.90000E+01
IM 3.20000E-01 2.88000E-01 1.00000E+01
NAME A4TI 5 0.826 PIM PAM PUM
ID 3.00000E-01 2.80000E-02 1.00000E+01
IT 3.20000E-01 1.1000E-01 1.00000E+01
IM 3.20000E-01 2.88000E-01 1.00000E+01
```

I would like to extract all data from the lines starting by IT either as individual strings

```
{'3.10000E-01 1.12000E-01 1.00000E+01'}
{'3.10000E-01 1.18000E-01 0.90000E+01'}
{'3.20000E-01 1.1000E-01 1.00000E+01'}
```

or cell array`

```
{'3.10000E-01'} {'1.12000E-01'} {'1.00000E+01'}
{'3.10000E-01'} {'1.18000E-01'} {'0.90000E+01'}
{'3.20000E-01'} {'1.10000E-01'} {'1.00000E+01'}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem. Here's a quick'n'dirty one (without regular expressions). Probably not the best way, but it does its job.

```
clc;
clear;

filename = "file.txt";
keyword = "IT";

fileID = fopen(filename);

float_results = {};
str_results = {};

while true
  line = fgetl(fileID); % Read a line from the file.
  
  if ~ischar(line) % Exit from the loop by EOF.
    break
  end
  
  if strncmp(line, keyword, length(keyword)) % Check if a line starts with a 'keyword'.
    % To get floating-point values (you probably want that, to manipulate with these numbers later on):
    float_values = sscanf(line, "IT %e %e %e"); % Returns a matrix of floating-point values, skips the 'IT' keyword.
    float_results = [float_results; float_values];
    
    % To get string values:
    line = erase(line, "IT "); % Delete the "IT " part of the line.
    str_results = [str_results; line];
  end
end

fclose(fileID);
```